# Compiling MapReduce programs - multiple files into jar with main

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have multiple java files that I want to compile into a MapReduce (jar) job.
The Mappers and the Reducers are in separate files, plus some custom helper classes (also separate). Furthermore, these files exists in different dirs. How do I compile and package these files, turn into jar, which launches on a class with `main`? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: Can you please give a code snippet so that it will be clear...

Comment: The easiest way to do it (IMHO) is use the hadoop plugin in eclipse and then just generate executable jar.